# MySQL query to get sum where month = January

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get renew_total sum from my database where expiry date = 1st month of year i.e: January

Here is my table user_pages structure

```
   id  |        expiry         |renew_total|renewal_flag|  self_managed |
    1  | 2017-01-08 15:03:57   |  1000     |      0     |        0      |
    2  | 2017-02-31 07:17:01   |  1500     |      0     |        0      |
```

I am trying this:

```
public function jan_renewal()
   {
        return $this->db->select("
        SELECT sum((renew_total*12)/100) 
        as janrenewal FROM user_pages 
        WHERE renewal_flag=0 
        AND self_managed = 0
        ");
   }
```

I am Not getting correct results as expected

> sum = 120

Comment: If you get sum as 1000 then it is correct?

Comment: What result are you getting? 120?

Comment: You are getting correct result . With month wise, you just shared first row value .

Comment: Question has "where month = January" in title, actual WHERE clause in code contains no such thing - what gives ...?

Comment: guy's  i said "I am Not getting correct results as expected" please read question again my query not working it gave me bunch of list of results not single result

Comment: _"please read question again"_ - yeah, do so yourself. _"my query not working it gave me bunch of list of results not single result"_ - you did not actually say anything about a "bunch of list of results", but only, in best "plain noobish", that it "wasn't working". So you go read [ask] now, please, to learn why "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description at all, and then you think about why you might be getting multiple results when you have data for multiple months, are grouping by (year and) month, and _neglected to_ limit this to a particular month as you said your plan was.

Comment: @JoshuaKisubi, i said i am not getting correct result as expected

Comment: @CBroe i am giving as much example to understand as i can i have good understanding of stackoverflow how to ask terms, kindly answer if you can, i have huge database, this is just an example

Comment: @CBroe i also tried "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiry, '%Y-%m-01' )" instead of group by in where clause i am getting null result

Comment: _"i have huge database, this is just an example"_ - and one that doesn't help at all so far. _"visit this link to see screenshot of result"_ - now that hardly looks like it could in any way come from the _two_ example records with data for one particular month each you have shown ... the stuff for March, April and May appears out of thin air. You're really doing as bad of a job of explaining an SQL problem as you probably could. Please go read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1427878) as well.

Comment: _"i also tried `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiry, '%Y-%m-01' )` instead of group by_" - where it is _what_ exactly ...? This makes about as much sense as `WHERE 'blue'` would - unless you want a specific thing to be blue, this is just _always_ true. You are interested in records for January only, so _look at_ the month part of the date only, and _compare it_ to the value you want: `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expiry, '%m' ) = '01'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MySQL's MONTH() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to select only dates in January:

```
SELECT SUM(renew_total) AS janrenewal 
FROM user_pages 
WHERE MONTH(expiry) = 1
AND renewal_flag = 0 
AND self_managed = 0;
```

Comment: your answer very closer to my question but when i run this query i am getting null results

Comment: @JamezRoz You will get null for any year when there are no `renew_total` values in January, of course.  Is that what you mean? If not, can you clarify?

Comment: i am not using group by i just want to filter result by month whatever it's 2017 or 2999 i want result of month = 1 take a look here you can see actual result window (upcoming renewals) you can see "jan" block is empty while we have month = 1 value inside db http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3027397/fbb3a1d449ec54f29aa82f323a09206c

Comment: i am using this query now after reading your answer 
   SELECT SUM ((renew_total*12)/100) 
   AS janrenewal
   FROM user_pages 
   WHERE MONTH(expiry) = 1
   AND renewal_flag = 0 
   AND self_managed = 0
   GROUP BY YEAR(expiry) but still result block is empty

Comment: Why are you *12 and /100? Your question does not say anything about that?

Comment: If you don't want it grouped by year, just 1 single total (for any years that you have in the DB) just remove that `GROUP BY YEAR()`.

Comment: renewal_total is monthly bases so first i need to *12 to get year total than  for currency conversation i need to /100, & i already mention it in question 
 return $this->db->select("SELECT sum((renew_total*12)/100)

Comment: it's ok i move math to view php file, your query is working now i am getting correct results please update your answer with this working query -> SELECT SUM(renew_total)
   AS janrenewal
   FROM user_pages 
   WHERE MONTH(expiry) = 1
   AND renewal_flag = 0 
   AND self_managed = 0 , let's contribute to stack-overflow community